# How can I send the data I get from the model and javascript to the controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I do the bus seat selection process. This is my view form. When this form is submitted, I get the number of clicks on the seat and their gender with javascript. But at the same time I want to get the flight information from a separate model and transfer it to the controls.

```
<form id="pForm" asp-controller="Ev" asp-action="Index" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="values" id="hidden" />
     <input type="submit" value="Devam Et" id="submit" />
</form>
```

transfer seat and gender to the array

```
array.push({ Gender: "Kadın", KoltukNo: tiklananKoltuk[0].attributes["koltukNo"].nodeValue});
```

submit with javascript

```
$("#pForm").submit(function (eventObj) {    
  var val = JSON.stringify(array);
  $("#hidden").val(val);
  return true;
});
```

My controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string values)
{               
    TempData["values"] = values;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Rezervasyon");
}
```

Now I want to send my voyage information from my model to my controller, how can I do this?

Comment: So you want to send the `values` to the `Rezervasyon` controller ?

Comment: my only problem is that I want to send expedition information from the model with values

Comment: I don't understand where the "expedition information" is coming from?

Comment: expedition, ie "sefer" is my model. I want to send the information from this model to the controller. Values ​​ ​​are also separate values ​​from javascript.

Comment: I don't see your model in the code and besides couldn't you just submit your info to that controller directly? rather than doing this useless redirection? or if you insist on this step just store your model in the `TempData` and cast it to its type in the target controller.

Comment: Can you share where you get the ' sefer' model data(such as view,database,controller action)?Do you mean you want to get the 'sefer' model data and the seat and gender array in the same controller action?